# Obtain the Total number of element in the Sorted Array that are within the given Range in O(1) time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, hashmap

I'm trying to write a class named Range, that takes an *array* of integers (unsorted) of length `n`, containing only numbers in the range are from `0` to `k`.

At first, I declare a constructor which will preprocess the array via Counting Sort algorithm.

Then I want to write `query()` method that takes two integer arguments: `a` and `b`, which form a range of numbers from `a` to `b` and returns the *total frequency* of all the elements in the *array* having the values within the given range.

*My code:*

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Range {

    private int[] a;
    private int k;

    public Range(int[] a, int k) {
        int index = 0;
        int[] counterArray = new int[k + 1];

        for (int i : a)
            counterArray[i]++;  // initialize counterArray

        for (int i = 0; i < counterArray.length; i++)
            while (0 < counterArray[i]) {
                a[index++] = i;
                counterArray[i]--;
            }   // end while()

        this.a = a;
        this.k = k;
    }   // end constructor()

    public int query(int a, int b) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(a);

    }   // end query()

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(a);
    }   // end toString()
}
```

I chose `HashMap` data structure because I need `query()` method to be executed in constant time **O(1)**.

So my question is: Is it possible to implement the method `query()` via `HashMap`?

If not, what are the alternatives? (Note: the time complexity should be **O(1)** for `query()`, not bothering about the space complexity).

*Code in the `main()` :*

```
int[] a = {13,12,13,1,2,0,0,1,3,4};
Range range = new Range(a, 13);
System.out.print(range); // prints [0,0,1,1,2,3,4,12,13,13] because array has been sorted

System.out.print(range.query(1, 4)); // calculating number of elements in the range [1, 4]
```

*Expected Output:*

```
5   // elements 1,1,2,3,4 are within the range [1, 4]
```

*Explanation:* provided arguments of the `query()` are: `a=1` and `b=4`, hence, values to be tested are `1,2,3,4`. The output should be `5` because there are `5` elements: `1,1,2,3,4`.

Comment: Provide a sample input and output.

Comment: So, you only want to know how many elements are between a and b? Meaning the result of the query is a single integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To obtain the number of elements in the given range (from `a` to `b` inclusive) in **O(1)** time after the array has been sorted, you don't need to use `HashMap`. Instead, you can reuse the `countingArray` by making it an instance variable.

This approach also requires a slight modification of the sorting in order to retain the values in the `countingArray` intact. It's done by introducing one additional variable.

***Note** that it's a good practice to *avoid mutating* the input, that why in the code I've used `Arrays.copyOf()` (you can remove it, if you consider it irrelevant for this exercise).*

I've extracted the logic responsible for sorting from the constructor into a separate method. And introduced a method which is meant to calculate the *cumulative count* for every number in the array (i.e. a number of element having values from `0` up to the current number inclusive).

So, after invoking method `init()` on the instance of `Range` we would be able to find the number of elements in the range from `a` to `b` by looking at the values stored in the `countingArray` at corresponding indices. And that would have a cost **O(1)**.

```
public class Range {
    private int[] arr;
    private int[] counterArray;
    private int k;
    
    private Range(int[] arr, int k) { // constructor is not exposed
        this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        this.counterArray = new int[k + 1];
        this.k = k;
    }
    
    public static Range getInstance(int[] arr, int k) {
        Range range = new Range(arr, k);
        range.init();
        return range;
    }
    
    private void init() {
        sort();
        sumUpCount();
    }
    
    private void sort() {

        for (int i : arr) {
            counterArray[i]++;
        }

        int index = 0;
        int copy;
        for (int i = 0; i < counterArray.length; i++) {
            copy = counterArray[i];
            while (0 < counterArray[i]) {
                arr[index++] = i;
                counterArray[i]--;
            }
            counterArray[i] = copy;
        }
    }
    
    private void sumUpCount() {
        for (int i = 1; i < counterArray.length; i++) {
            counterArray[i] += counterArray[i - 1];
        }
    }
    
    public int query(int a, int b) {
        
        return a == 0 ? counterArray[b] :  counterArray[b] - counterArray[a - 1];
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {13,12,13,1,2,0,0,1,3,4};
    Range range = Range.getInstance(a, 13);
    System.out.print(range.query(1,4));
}
```

*Output:*

```
5
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander, i didnt think about it that way. Could you more elaborate about the sumUpCount(). The operations done be that function are applied and update to counterArray[]? i cant totally understand the flow.

Comment: @Caveira Please have a look at the very last sentences where I've explained how *cumulative count* is being calculated. After executing `sumUpCount()`, `counterArray` would contain at index `0` the number of elements having the value of `0`, at index `1` the number of elements having the values `0` and `1`, and so on.

Comment: Why cant i implement the sort inside the constructor? it sounds reasonable to me that once the constructor is opened then the first and most important step is to sort the given input.

Comment: @Caveira You can. From the perspective of clean-coding, it's a good practice to keep constructors free from heavy logic (it improves readability, and in some cases help with testing). If you want to insure a new instance of `Range` has it's array already sorted before invoking method `query()` on it, you can make constructor `private` and expose a `static` method, which would return an initialized instance of `Range`. It's fairly easy to implement, I can show it.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Caveira Updated the answer. Have a look at the method `getInstance()`, that the only way to obtain a new instance of `Range`. All the initialization logic is guaranteed to be executed and end-user might even not be aware of it. You can encounter such approach in different classes from the JDK and in some frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to cache/precompute the return values of query(), you need to create a composite key, that holds both values. The easiest way to do that is to use a string that holds both numbers divided by a separator. Separator is important otherwise composite key(21, 5) = "215" and key(2, 15) = "215". With separator that would be "21;5" and "2;15" respectivly.

```java
private String key(int a, int b) {
    return String.format("%d;%d", a, b);
}
```

Then for each composite key possible you put the value into HashMap. In the query(a, b) method you just get the value from the Map.

```java
public query(int a, int b) {
    return map.get(key(a, b));
}
```

The downside of this approach is that creation of this object is pretty expensive.